# Is there a way to disable IPv6 in Google's Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, localhost, ipv6

I'm developing websites in a Windows 7 machine.

When I've installed Firefox I've found some performance issue specially on connecting to the localhost, googling around I've discovered that it's related to the use of IPv6 by the browser to resolve urls.

Using `about: config` and setting `network.dns.disableIPv6` to true the problem is gone.

Now I've the same issue with Google Chrome, but I can't find a way (if there's a way) to do the same I've done with Firefox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post this question on http://superuser.com

Comment: Just posted! http://superuser.com/questions/174715/is-there-a-way-to-disable-ipv6-in-googles-chrome