# How to disable ipV6 in Google Chrome (version 45)?

Tags: google-chrome, ipv6

I recently updated Chrome on my developer machine to v45. This update seems to set my client Ip to always use IpV6. Some of the applications I am developing locally require me to use Ipv4 so I need to disable Ipv6 on chrome. I tried solutions mentioned in

[Is there a way to disable IPv6 in Google's Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459002/is-there-a-way-to-disable-ipv6-in-googles-chrome)

but that doesn't seem to resolve my problem.

Comment: The application should not care what protocols are used in the data-link or network layers.

Answer (score 9):

### Short answer

The Chrome's method for resolving names (async-dns) is ignoring the OS's IPv4/IPv6 precedence.

You can try to launch  Chrome from the console with the flag `--disable-async-dns` but, obviously, you'll loose that functionality.

### Long answer

There are two reasons because you can't disable IPv6 in Chrome:

- Google is not providing anymore the option to deactivate IPv6 since [1149303005](https://codereview.chromium.org/1149303005).
- Your OS must implement the "policy table" described in [RFC3484](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt). With it you should be able to give IPv4 precedence for all applications, inclunding Chrome. Nevertheless, Chrome is not working as expected: there is a known issue [516305](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516305&can=1&q=ipv6&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) not fixed.

So you must disable "async dns" or you have to hack it out of Chrome, for example:

- Using the `etc/hosts` file.
- Choose (or deploy) an IPv4-only DNS and configure it in your OS's network configuration.
- Install a web proxy with IPv6 disabled, then configure Chrome for using it.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the `--disable-async-dns` flag was removed; see [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/1149303005) for the details. If it wasn't removed, at the very least it doesn't seem to do anything anymore on Windows. *sigh* back to developing using Firefox...

Comment: Previous link is wrong link. [see here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432236) for the actual details.
Of course it was after the edit timeout that I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, you can add the ipv4 address and the hostname to the hosts file (located: c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). Then the browser does not look up the dns to get the ip address but uses the ip address that you have provided in the hosts file.

On ios/mac the hostfile is located here: /private/etc/hosts

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks! And to know the IPv4 of the hostname: `ping -4 your-host.com`